# AWS API Gateway custom authorizer. How to access principalId in lambda

Tags: java, api, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I am trying to set up a custom authorizer in API Gateway.

I can get it to forward a request with a valid token to the lambda function specified in the API method. I cannot figure out how to access the principalId passed on by my authorizer though.

When executing the request I get the following in the Cloud watch log:

```
Authorizer result body before parsing:
{
  "principalId": "16",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Condition": {},
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:****:***/null/*/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
      },
      {
        "Condition": {},
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": [],
        "Effect": "Deny"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So how do I access the principalId in my lambda function? Is the object even passed on to lambda? And if it is not, how do I get at least the principalId to passed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The principalId can (and by default is) forwarded to the Lambda implementation. Depending on your mapping, the principalId should appear in the context variable.

> You can access the principalId value in a mapping template using the $context.authorizer.principalId variable. This is useful if you want to pass the value to the backend. For more information, see Accessing the $context Variable.

[Use API Gateway Custom Authorizers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have any mapping whatsoever, working perfectly now.